# Keep javascript changes if page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a very simple system where if the user clicks on a colour, some parts of the page turn that colour. But my question is, Is there a way to save this colour? That if the person refreshes the page the colour is still there?

This is the concept of my code, I made it very simple but in my project its way bigger. This is how i've done it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#Blue").click(function() {
       $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#0069D9');
        

    });

    $("#Purple").click(function() {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#563B64');
        
    });

    $("#Green").click(function() {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#00BA4B');
        
    });

    $("#Yellow").click(function() {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#FFFF00');
        
    });

    $("#Orange").click(function() {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#FF5E00');
        
    });

    $("#Red").click(function() {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#CC0000');
    
    });
});
```

```css
.colorchange {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button id="Blue">Blue</button>
<button id="Purple">Purple</button>
<button id="Green">Green</button>
<button id="Yellow">Yellow</button>
<button id="Orange">Orange</button>
<button id="Red">Red</button>
           
           
<button class="btn btn-primary colorchange" type="submit">This color changes</button>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use localStorage?

Comment: What do you mean? How do I do that?

Comment: Do some research on localstorage, sessionstorage and cookies. Than pick the one that's best fitted for your situation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Do you want to keep the changes for all users that visit your page or just for one? Each of this has a different implementation and one is more complex than the other

Comment: u have registered users? Then you can connect their id's to some kind of individual styling.

Comment: @Feudelcosine148, check my answer. Its the solution you are looking for.

Comment: If the color change is for temporary purpose then go for localStorage, Else you can do a customized styling mechanism like gmail theme. For doing that you need a backend system which will store the user preferences.

Comment: @Feudelcosine148, you got a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `localStorage`. It will store the selected color in browser's memory and when user refreshes the page, you can read the stored colour and set it using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Blue").click(function() {
       $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#0069D9');        
       saveColor('#0069D9');
    });

    $("#Purple").click(function() {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#563B64');
        saveColor('#563B64');
    });

    $("#Green").click(function() {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#00BA4B');
        saveColor('#00BA4B');
    });

    $("#Yellow").click(function() {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#FFFF00');
        saveColor('#FFFF00');
    });

    $("#Orange").click(function() {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#FF5E00');
        saveColor('#FF5E00');        
    });

    $("#Red").click(function() {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', '#CC0000');
        saveColor('#CC0000');    
    });

    function saveColor(color)
    {
        localStorage.setItem("selectedcolor", color);
    }

    var clr = localStorage.getItem("selectedcolor");
    if(clr != '' && clr != null)
    {
        $(".colorchange").css('background-color', clr);
    }
});
```

Comment: If `clr` key is not found in `localStorage`, then it will return `null`, not empty string. So, your if condition at the bottom might need to be updated.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, thank you for pointing it out. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` to save different values. `localStorage` stores key-value pairs.

Example:

```
 localStorage.setItem("BlueDiv", "#0069D9");
```

You can then retrieve the data like this:

```
localStorage.getItem("BlueDiv"); //Returns "#0069D9"
```

Don't forget to set colors to the saved values on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cookies` and `localstorage` to store the changes